# Не работает наклон градиента в background-image: linear-gradient (45deg);

Tags: css, linear-gradient

Проверял в разных браузерах Chrome, opera, mozilla, ошибка остается.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быт причина?

[image: Ошибка не корректное значение свойства]

После удаления to left ошибка остается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `to-left` уберите.

Comment: Потому что не надо два раза указывать направление :) `to left` = `270deg`.

Comment: Не помогает( ошибка осталась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё работает `Microsoft Edge`

[image]

Скорее всего дело в том как вы добавили новый стиль, или аргументах(уберите `to-left`).

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #EECFBA, #C5DDE8);
```

Comment: Из аргументов to left удалял не сработало скрин выше размещал, стиль проверил верно задан.

Comment: В каком браузере и на какой странице вы пытались это осуществить?

Comment: Переписал сейчас свойство заново начиная с градусов и всё заработало, не понял в чём была ошибка(

Comment: Браузер chrome ver. 106